# Как сгенерировать 5 неповторяющихся чисел дающих в сумме 100?

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Хочу реализовать генерацию 5  чисел от 0 до 100, в сумме эти числа = 100, не должно быть повторений и должны быть использованы все варианты перебора.

Мой код:

```py
for a in range(101):
    for b in range(101):
        for c in range(101):
            for d in range(101):
                for e in range(101):
                    if a + b + c + d + e == 100:
                       print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Порядок чисел важен? *100 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0* и *0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 100* - это разные комбинации?

Comment: Да это разные комбинации. Порядок числе важен а это а, b это b и тд, так как их применяю в дальнейшем в вычислениях. Данный код правильно генерирует числа, но очень долго. максимум 4 числа возможно таким способом

Comment: "не должно быть повторений" - что это значит?

Comment: Вам нужна одна случайная комбинация? Или вам нужны все возможные комбинации?

Comment: все возможные, вот пример если запустить только это                                                                        
 '''for a in range(101):
         for b in range(101):
               for c in range(101):
                     if a + b + c == 100:
                        print(a, b, c)

Comment: Генерируешь 5 случайных чисел. Нормализуешь сумму в 100. Если получил дубликаты - повторяешь. *Мой код* В твоём коде от случайности нет даже тени.

Comment: @Akina, генерация случайной комбинации с равномерным распределением - прикольная и не такая простая задача. Нормализация суммы будет приводить к некоторой неравномерности распределения.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если `x(1..5)` распределены равномерно, то почему распределение `const * x(1..5)` станет неравномерным? И потом - про распределение вроде бы разговора вообще не было. Впрочем, автор радикально изменил вопрос.

Comment: @Akina, сумма независимых случайных величин имеет распределение в виде колокола. Я думаю, это приведёт к тому что после нормализации "примерно равные" комбинации получат преимущество в распределении, а комбинации с больших разбросом значений будут встречаться реже. Или наоборот? Задайте вопрос, будет интересно поразбираться.

Answer (score 2):

Раз вам нужны все комбинации, то ваш способ, если его немного модифицировать так, чтобы плохие комбинации не генерировались вообще, будет самым быстрым. Однако "очень долго" - это естественно, число вариантов для суммы 100 довольно велико.

```
n = 6
for a in range(n+1):
    for b in range(n-a+1):
        for c in range(n-a-b+1):
            for d in range(n-a-b-c + 1):
                e = n-a-b-c-d
                print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Или с запоминанием, чтобы сократить вычисления:

```
n = 6
for a in range(n+1):
    sa = n - a
    for b in range(sa+1):
        sb = sa - b
        for c in range(sb+1):
            sc = sb - c
            for d in range(sc + 1):
                e = sc - d
                print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def combinations(t, n):

    board = [0] * n
    
    def search(k, s):
        if k == n - 1:
            board[k] = s
            yield board
            return
        for v in range(t - s + 1):
            board[k] = v
            yield from search(k + 1, s + v)

    return map(tuple, search(0, 0))


for a, b, c, d, e in combinations(100, 5):
    print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

> ```
> $ time python combinations.py | wc -l
> 4598126
>
> real  0m10.356s
> user  0m10.348s
> sys   0m0.096s
> ```

Число комбинаций не такое огромное. Если *n* - количество слагаемых, *t* - сумма комбинации, то число комбинаций будет равно *Cnk(t + n - 1, n - 1)*. Проверка:

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> import math
> @>>> t = 100
> @>>> n = 5
> @>>> math.comb(t + n - 1, n - 1)
> 4598126
> ```

Comment: Насчёт времени работы - я так понимаю, print у вас при таком использовании не настоящий, а вывод перенаправляется в wс, который считает переводы строк и соответственно количество комбинаций?

Comment: @MBo, `print` настоящий. Если перенаправить в файл, время будет такое же. Если печатать в консоль, время будет больше. Время консоли никому не интересно. Я сравнивал наши решения у себя: ваше - 8 секунд, моё - 10 секунд. Это не много. :)

Comment: У меня получается почему-то 2.6 vs 5 c при формировании строки `s = f'{a} {b} {c} {d}'`, но без печати. Да, большой разницы быть не должно.

Comment: @MBo, печать в вопросе только для примера, я уверен. ТС делает какой-то комбинаторный поиск, печать ему не нужна. И, конечно, ваш код самый быстрый и простой.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

all_combinations = itertools.combinations(range(100), 5)
valid_combinations = [combo for combo in all_combinations if sum(combo) == 100]
print(valid_combinations)
```

Comment: Нет комбинации *0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 100*.